# Regex to match repetition of letters in a string input of letters in flex

Tags: regex

I m writing a flex program where the user puts as input letters of the range `[A-E]` for example the user input is: `"ABC"`.
I wanna know with which regex i could spot the case that the user uses the same letter two or more times,for example the user input would be `"AAB"` or `"ABA"`.
None of the similar questions that exist helped me so any answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the FTP  server details by using the following regex. Pick that text up and replace it will whatever is your need.

Regex: `'(?:(?:\[ash)\d+(?:\])\n)(?:(?:ftp|FTP|Ftp).*\s=\s(.*))'`

In this, while replacing you can use the following regex to copy paste from source but change the rest on yourself.

Append your data after this regex.

Regex: `'(?:(?:\[ash)\d+(?:\])\n)(?:(?:ftp|FTP|Ftp).*\s=\s)'`

You have to use some logic within your program.
for e.g.
First, save the data which regex fetches.
Remove a group from that you do not want, using the second regex
Append your correct FTP server info.
Replace the new text with original and replace in the original string.

Good Luck. It is not straightforward, give it some time.